# Send Voice To PC Modem

Tags: c#, modem

I try to send voice to my computer's modem with this method "Write" with the serial port
but when i play a wave file i hear noise

I use this code:

```
     modemPort.Write("ATZ" + "\r");
     modemPort.Write("AT+FCLASS=8" + "\r");
     modemPort.Write("AT+VTX" + "\r");         
     modemPort.Write("ATDT" + "123456" + "\r");
     modemPort.Write(fileByte, 44, fileByte.Length - 44);
      // hang up
     modemPort.Write("ATH" + "\r");
```

Comment: Sent VTX and wait for CONNECT after the ATDT completes and the call is connected. Ensure the encoding of the pcm data is supported (AT+VSM). Ensure your implementing some buffering rather than dumping a huge blob of data. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set#Transmitting_audio_data

Comment: thanks for your answer